# Error: Library not loaded "/lib/libgridstore.0.dylib" in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I’m getting import error `cannot load library /usr/local/lib/libgridstore.0.dylib`

Environment:

```
macOS Big Sur v11.6.5
python version: 3.10.0b4
```

Steps to produce the issue:

```
#Created virtual env via pyenv
pyenv virtualenv 3.10.0b4 onDemand
#Could not activate so had to run the following
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
#Activated virtual env
pyenv activate onDemand
#Installed libraries
python -m pip install pandas
python -m pip install griddb_python

When running the sample app, the following message appeared:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Angga/Documents/GitHub/OnDemandTraining/Python/tutorial.py", line 3, in <module>
    import griddb_python as griddb
  File "/Users/Angga/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0b4/envs/onDemand/lib/python3.10/site-packages/griddb_python.py", line 21, in <module>
    import _griddb_python
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Angga/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0b4/envs/onDemand/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_griddb_python.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgridstore.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Angga/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0b4/envs/onDemand/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_griddb_python.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I was getting an ImportError. I found that the package for GridDB Python Client already includes C Client Library, so I don't think I need to install GridDB C Client on MacOS